# adView banner error

Tags: android, request, adview, banner-ads

I am using an adMob banner in my application but when I run it, I got an errors as bellow:

```
12-17 12:32:19.098: E/Trace(1244): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-17 12:32:19.727: D/dalvikvm(1244): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 55K, 3% free 8039K/8259K, paused 60ms, total 63ms
12-17 12:32:19.907: I/dalvikvm-heap(1244): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.900MB for 12582928-byte allocation
12-17 12:32:20.008: D/dalvikvm(1244): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 2% free 20326K/20615K, paused 30ms+19ms, total 97ms
12-17 12:32:21.677: W/Ads(1244): No Google Analytics: Library Incompatible.
12-17 12:32:21.697: D/AndroidRuntime(1244): Shutting down VM
12-17 12:32:21.697: W/dalvikvm(1244): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.antiwal7amel/com.app.antiwal7amel.MenuActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.app.antiwal7amel.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:44)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-17 12:32:21.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     ... 11 more
```

I am using it as bellow :

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity   {
    AdView  adView ;
    @Override   

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
 AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
 ad.loadAd(request);
```

And inside my manifest also :

```
   <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"></activity>
```

But I don't know where is the problem ! I googled it a lot with no solution

Comment: What is line 44 of your MenuActivity?

Comment: Are you sure there is an `AdView` with id `adView` in your `activity_main` layout?

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper please post your `activity_main.xml` too

Comment: @ndsmyter thanks alot ! I had two layouts ! one with activity_main and the other with activitymain ! and I was pointing to the wrong one ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is situated in `ad.loadAd(request);` this is probably a problem with the id `adView` not existing in your `activity_main` layout.

Or maybe there is something wrong with the initialisation of the `AdRequest`. Maybe you can check why one of these elements is `null`. Because when you know which of them is `null` you can try to solve the problem.